# axis2 headers on server side

Tags: java, web-services, soap, header, apache-axis

On server side one can get request object and after business logic returns response to client.
Below is the server side function that gets request from client and return response.
How can client request headers can be get on server side? I want to see those headers.

```
public String findPerson(FindPersonRequest findPersonaRequest) {

    System.out.println("clientRequest = " + clientRequest);
    ..........
    return response;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a look at complete message with headers why not use Eclipse TCP/IP monitor? Here, simple tutorial:

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/how-to-trace-soap-message-in-eclipse-ide/

Answer (score 0):

I believe [MessageContext](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/context/MessageContext.html) is what you're looking for...

Also a short tutorial [here](http://amilachinthaka.blogspot.de/2008/11/accessing-axis2-information-at-client.html).